# Echoing function into Wordpress NextGen gallery

Tags: functions, shortcode

Is there anyway to echo a function into a wordpress shortcode?
heres my code:

```
<div id="subscription">
<?php echo do_shortcode('[nggallery id=$ID]');?>
</div>
```

$ID is a function that grabs a number generated in the url

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

how about something like

```
<div id="subscription">
 <?php echo do_shortcode('[nggallery id='.$ID.']');?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The plugin - Shortcode Exec PHP http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/shortcode-exec-php/
might be what you are looking for. It converts PHP into shortcode